# How to set dynamically the width of button according to its text content in android?

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I want to have button size according to the text content. For example, if size of text is about 4 letters then width of button be should big enough to adjust 4 letters only.Here is My Code:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.layoutTags);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  //Can also be done in xml by android:orientation="vertical"
layout.setWeightSum(1);
layout.removeAllViews();
layout.invalidate();
float rowneed = ((float) count1 / 5);
k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ceil(rowneed); i++) {
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.removeAllViews();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        btnTag = new Button(getContext());
        btnTag.setHeight(15);
        btnTag.setWidth(1);
        btnTag.setMinimumWidth(155);
        btnTag.setMinimumHeight(135);

        if (k < count1) {
            btnTag.setText(filteredTags.get(k).gettagName());
            btnTag.setId(k);
            k++;
            btnTag.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            btnTag.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        Log.e("count", " " + k + " " + count1 + " " + ceil(rowneed) + " " + edtTag.getText().toString());
        btnTag.setTextSize(7);
        btnTag.setGravity(0);

        row.addView(btnTag);
    }
    layout.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: Why not have wrap_content for width and height in xml instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds

Comment: @ShashankUdupa ,because we are creating multiple buttons dynamically. thank you –

Comment: @RavindraShekhawat thank you for the link. But ,I want to resize a button not a text. Any Help!

Comment: You just need to change view use button instead of textview throughout code. Atleast try first there is no such   function provided by android to resize view dynamically on basis of text size  so you will have to put efforts ..:-)

Comment: try 
`btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Comment: Thank You!. @Naz141 it is not working for me

Comment: Did you remove these 

`btnTag.setHeight(15);
        btnTag.setWidth(1);
        btnTag.setMinimumWidth(155);
        btnTag.setMinimumHeight(135);
 btnTag.setGravity(0);` and use the above code?

Comment: @Naz141 yes, I have removed.

Answer (score 0):

Set LayoutParams in java

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = button.getLayoutParams();
p.width= ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
button.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: ..please read question again she is creating button dynamically not using xml .

Comment: Thank You!. @KushaalSingla it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
1.0f));
```